# Tensorflow fine tuning tutorial without Bazel

Tags: tensorflow

I am using the Google Research tutorial for fine tuning the Inception model.

[The tutorial can be found here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception/README.md#how-to-fine-tune-a-pre-trained-model-on-a-new-task)

The tutorial uses Bazel.

I have access to my institution's GPU that doesn't have Bazel installed on it.

Is there a way I can complete this fine tuning tutorial without using Bazel?

Comment: Bazel is not crucial for running this tutorial, because it doesn't really need to build anything... just invoke shell scripts and Python scripts. Therefore (for example) instead of `bazel build //inception:download_and_preprocess_flowers`, you could run [`download_and_preprocess_flowers.sh`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/4e5e2497f7ef50810335f6cf706d475553c5a75f/inception/inception/data/download_and_preprocess_flowers.sh) directly, but you might need to modify some of the paths (e.g. replacing `$BUILD_SCRIPT` with `python build_image_data.py`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.Just check
[this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#4.).In the section 5.